Dynamic SQL query being truncated to the length of one value
I have a SQL query in which I'm returning a string containing an HTML <tr> for each row returned by my query, see foot of this message for an example.
As you can see in my example below, one 'column', if you will, is being converted into an nvarchar(4000). What I would expect this to do, perhaps naively, is convert the data in that column into an nvarchar(4000) but to then append to that all the other columns and '<td>' etc, such that the overall length of the string returned is longer than 4000 characters. However, what's happening is that the entire string being returned, i.e. '<tr>' + ... + '</tr>' is limited to 4000 characters in length. In some instances, the data in just one column is so long that the entire string exceeds 4000 characters and thus gets cut off, for example:
<tr><td>12345678-01-01</td><td>12345678</td><td>APPLE</td><td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td><td>03/04/2018 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla par.</td><td>03/04/2018</t

As you can see, the string returned ends in '</t', which is incomplete HTML and thus causes issues when trying the pass this HTML to javascript to do something with it.
It's worth mentioning before anyone tries to answer, but for really boring reasons that I won't get into here, I CAN'T use nvarchar(max) in this circumstance, the best I can do is nvarchar(4000). Why does this behaviour force the entire string returned to be an nvarchar(4000) as opposed to truncating the value within the specific column and then simply appending the rest of the string to that, such that it can exceed 4000 chars? I.e. I absolutely get the fact that a column's data type might be nvarchar(4000), but If I concatenated two such columns together I'd expect to be able to do so without truncation.
Is there any way I can get round this without using nvarchar(max)? Also, whilst I absolutely appreciate suggestions that I could build this using technologies other than SQL, let's just assume for the purposes of this question that SQL server is my only option.
    select
    '<tr>'
        + '<td>' + isnull(stu.stu_code,'') + '</td>'
        + '<td>' + isnull(sta.sta_name,'') + '</td>'
        + '<td>' + replace(replace(
            case 
                when isnull(convert(nvarchar(4000),ccl.ccl_note),'') = ''
                then isnull(convert(nvarchar(4000),scc.scc_note),'')
                else isnull(convert(nvarchar(4000),ccl.ccl_note),'')
            end, char(10),''),char(13),'')  
        + '</td>'
        + '<td>' + case when scc.scc_cred is null then '' else format(scc.scc_cred,'dd/MM/yyyy') end + '</td>' 
+ '</tr>'

from ...


why do it in the sql in the first pace, make your html code in the application

Use XML instead

Use nvarchar(max), unless you're on sql server 2000, then you should upgrade and then use nvarchar(max)

You can cast() the result

Seriously though, this sometimes happens if  you don't use N'' around all the strings you're concating. In your example, you don't use N'...' at all which is wrong. I'm not sure why, but in some cases, sql server doesn't properly upcasts under concatenation. But anyway, if your string do overshoot, then you have no choice but to do something more complex

I won't get into here on the contrary, you have to get into them. You're using completely inappropriate tools to do whatever you want. There are proper tools, starting from the built-in Reporting Services that create HTML reports, to ASP.NET Core, to .NET template libraries like Scriban. And the least flexible case, generating XML with tr tags. String concatenation just isn't realistic. Imagine what will happen if scc_note contains <.

This Simple Talk blog post shows how to create an entire HTML table with FOR XML, complete with conditional CSS classes. Nowadays we'd use STRING_AGG for concatenations, possibly FORMAT for easier date formatting, but the main features are the same

Just to expand on my comment ... Note the null's
Select td = col1
      ,null
      ,td = col2
      ,null
      ,td = col3
 From YourTable
 For XML Path('tr')


This will take care of < and other characters that aren't allowed in HTML too.

This is interesting. Why is NULLs making it "gather" all values together instead of each having own  wrapper?

@siggemannen  I honestly don't know.  It is a technique I saw years ago and thought "Huh... Son of B!tch."

It sounds like you actually do want nvarchar(max), but you want to truncate each column to 4000.
So use LEFT
select
    '<tr>'
        + '<td>' + isnull(stu.stu_code,'') + '</td>'
        + '<td>' + isnull(sta.sta_name,'') + '</td>'
        + '<td>' +
         convert(nvarchar(max),
           left(
             replace(replace(
               isnull(
                 nullif(ccl.ccl_note, ''),
                 nullif(scc.scc_note, '')
               ),
               nchar(10), ''), nchar(13), ''
             ),
             4000
           )
         )
        + '</td>'
        + '<td>' + isnull(convert(nvarchar(max), scc.scc_cred, 103), '') + '</td>' 
+ '</tr>'

from etc

I agree @JohnCappelleti that you should instead use FOR XML. A slightly different version:
select
  (
    select
      td
    from (values
      (convert(nvarchar(max), isnull(stu.stu_code,''))),
      (isnull(sta.sta_name,'')),
      (
       left(
         replace(replace(
           isnull(
             nullif(ccl.ccl_note, ''),
             nullif(scc.scc_note, '')
           ),
           nchar(10), ''), nchar(13), ''
         ),
         4000
       ),
      ),
      (isnull(convert(nvarchar(max), scc.scc_cred, 103), ''))
    ) as v(td)
    for xml path('tr')
  )
from etc

